# Compatibility Nvidia and Mathematica 11.3

Tags: neural-networks

I am wondering about the compatibility between Mathematica 11.3 (Windows or Linux) and the Nvidia Quadro P5200 provided in the ThinkPad P72.

Can I be sure that Mathematica will be able to detect and use the Nvidia card to accelerate the function NetTrain for example?

Best,
N.B.

Comment: See [`TargetDevice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetDevice.html) and check the  compute capability of your GPU.

Comment: you can use `CUDAInformation[]` to test the compatibility of your graphics card

Comment: The problem is that I do not have this laptop yet; I want to buy only if I am sure that my computations will be accelerated thanks to this card using NetTrain.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/tutorial/Reference.html#1803279895